# Screen does not turn off when inactive

Tags: 16.04, brightness, lock-screen

Recently I have noticed that the brightness and lock settings to turn off the screen after a period of inactivity are being ignored.

I have my settings at 1 minute and to lock the screen when the screen turns off but my computer never seems to turn the screen off.

I have seen similar questions where people are noting an issue where the screens turn back on and the lock screen is showing but I am not getting the computer to lock at all.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## I can offer a workaround to this

---

Never mind the settings in the GUI, you can lock your screen and send your screens into standby via the command line

---

To lock your screen you could use

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

or (if don't use gnome3)

```
xdg-screensaver lock
```

and to turn off your monitors (standby) you could use

```
xset dpms force off
```

Now, since you don't want to do this manually, but after a couple of minutes idle time, we need to find out how long you have been idle.
This can be done with `xprintidle`

```
sudo apt-get install xprintidle
```

`xprintidle` will return miliseconds of (xserver) idletime

Now, lets combine this into a script(*). Use your favorite editor to copy/paste the following, modifying the `IDLE_TIME` to your liking

```
nano /home/yourusername/idle_stby_lock_screen.sh
```

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# Wanted trigger timeout in milliseconds.
IDLE_TIME=$((5*60*1000))  # replace the '5' with how many minutes you'd like


# Sequence to execute when timeout triggers.
trigger_cmd() {
    echo "Triggered action $(date)"
}

sleep_time=$IDLE_TIME
triggered=false

while sleep $(((sleep_time+999)/1000)); do
    idle=$(xprintidle)
    if [ $idle -ge $IDLE_TIME ]; then
        if ! $triggered; then
            gnome-screensaver-command -l
            export DISPLAY=:0; xset dpms force off
            triggered=true
            sleep_time=$IDLE_TIME
        fi
    else
        triggered=false
        # Give 150 ms buffer to avoid frantic loops shortly before triggers.
        sleep_time=$((IDLE_TIME-idle+150))
    fi
done
```

Then make it executable with

```
chmod +x /home/yourusername/idle_stby_lock_screen.sh
```

You can test it out on the commandline

```
/home/yourusername/idle_stby_lock_screen.sh
```

if you are content with it, you can add it to the startup of your Ubuntu, like [described in these answers here](https://askubuntu.com/q/814/783023) or with the "Startup" app in Ubuntu - just make sure to use the absolute path to your script.

Comment: While this solution would work I am not sure how viable it is when screen locking/screen saver is supposed to be a built in feature of Ubuntu.

Comment: @JoeW, as I said: a workaround

Comment: Also, I use this to make sure my screens **stay** in standby, because sometimes they wake up, for whatever reason...