# Ubuntu 22.04 only blanks, but does not turn off screen

Tags: display, power-management, 22.04

Recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, and it seems like the power-saving feature does not actually turn off the screen(s) after X minutes, but just blanks them. When I manually run `xset dpms force off`, they do properly turn off and go to sleep, but this and related solutions (e.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/1004163/29252) do feel rather kludgy.

Any suggestions for how to fix this "properly"?

Comment: Also reported as bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1971434 (not 100% sure if g-s-d is the right component, though).

Comment: Added an affect me to your launchpad bug report

Comment: The screens won't turn off when the Power Profile is set to "Performance". They turn off when it is "Balanced" or "Power Saver".

Comment: A workaround that seems to work for me: after login, lock the screens once manually using Super-L. After that, powersave works as intended.

Comment: sometimes its the wrong displaymanager (gdm3, lightdm, slim, sddm, ...). If there is only one working (is it?) try "sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3" and confirm gdm3 (which is needed for Gnome based screensaver functionality).

Answer (score 0):

I detected the issue in my system. Since I'm using a desktop, I managed to solve the problem by replacing the HDMI cable with a DisplayPort cable. Now, my monitor completely turns off. I hope this helps.